# How to add Rich Text Box in Custom Widget in Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity-5

I have created a Custom widget in Sitefinity. I want to add a rich Textbox in the widget.
For detail see below images.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a rad editor control to your designer .ascx file

```
 <telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="RadEditor1" Height="400px" Width="680px" SkinID="MinimalSetOfTools">
     </telerik:RadEditor>
```

You may also need to add telerik web ui refference on the top of the .ascx file in case is not added

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add RadEditor, you needs to perform following steps.

1)In .ascx file add the namespace as shown

```
  <%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
```

2)And replace your textbox with following code.

```
    <telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="Mytext" Height="400px" Width="680px" SkinID="MinimalSetOfTools" CssClass="sfTxt">
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

3)you need to make some changes in the .js file of your widget as well because RadEditor has its own methods to get or set its html. You can use get_html() and set_html() instead of using val() in its .js file